# VIM: Referring to current buffer in key mappings

Tags: vim, keymapping

I would like to map a certain key mapping to make the Python interpreter run the current edited buffer in VIM.

> What I'm doing now (*manually*):
>
> ```
> :!python <FILENAME>
> ```

But I'd like the  variable to actually be a variable, so that a mapping could be in my .vimrc and work for any file I open in VIM.

I'd also like to know how to chain several commands, so that instead of doing:

```
:w
:!python <FILENAME>
```

I could map both of them to a single command. Something like

```
:w ; :!python <FILENAME>
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers. The final solution was to do:

```
:cmap <KEY> :w<CR>:!python %<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` in vim refers to the current filename.

You can do a mapping like `nnoremap <leader>r :!./%<CR>` to execute the current script if the shebang line is set.

Answer (score 1):

The percent sign (%) will be replaced by the current filename

For the key macro:

```
 map yourkey :w^V^J!python %^V^J
```

where ^V is Ctrl-V and ^J is Ctrl-J (linefeed)